# How does GDI+ support floating point values?

Tags: windows, floating-point, gdi+, gdi

Given that GDI+ is a wrapper around GDI, how does it handle floating point values? I don't see any support for floating point co-ordinates in the GDI documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDI+ is mostly NOT a wrapper around GDI. It didnt gain much traction among driver developers etc, so most of it is implemented in software. It does handle floating points (eg PointF, SizeF) but rather poorly. I find that rounding the values back up to integers provides the most attractive rendered content.

See [Is GDI+ just a layer on top of GDI, or something new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103489/is-gdi-just-a-layer-on-top-of-gdi-or-something-new)